# How to mock a generic type function OR create a generic function at run time?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, mocking

I have a generic function like this:

```
public class DataRetriever<TData, TFilter>
    where TData : class, IData<TData, TFilter>, new()
    where TFilter : IFilter
{
    public static List<TData> List(TFilter filter)
    {
    }
}
```

It is used at different classes like this:

```
var authorFilter = new AuthorFilter("A");  // Author with last name started with A
var bookList = DataRetriever<Book, AuthorFilter>.List(authorFilter);

var userFilter = new UserFilter("A");  // User with last name started with A
var userList = DataRetriever<User, UserFilter>.List(userFilter);
```

I need to mock the DataRetriever.List function as it is calling the DB.  One way I can do is to inject each use type of these functions as a Func parameter to the constructor and call them like this:

```
public UsageReport(Func<AuthorFilter, List<Book>> bookListFunc, 
                   Func<UserFilter, List<User>> userListFunc)
{
    _bookListFunc = bookListFunc ?? DataRetriever<Book, AuthorFilter>.List;
    _userListFunc= userListFuncn ?? DataRetriever<User, UserFilter>.List;
}

var bookList = _bookListFunc(authorFilter);
var userList = _userListFunc(userFilter);
```

However, if this class is used the DataRetriever.List in 10 different ways, I need to inject 10 of them.  Also, if there is a new case added, I need to inject a new one.

I am thinking to create a builder or provider that can give me the function with the parameter types at run time like this:

```
public interface IDataRetrieverListProvider
{
    Func Get ()
}
```

Then I can just inject that IDataRetrieverListProvider and mock it to provide me the function I can use for unit test.

```
public UsageReport(IDataRetrieverListProvider dataRetrieverListProvider)
                   
Func bookListFunc = _dataRetrieverListProvider.Get(Book, AuthorFilter);
var bookList = bookListFunc(authorFilter);
```

I don't know if it is possible to do it as I think the returned Func must use the concrete type, not the generic type.

Any suggestions to have a better way to implement it or mock it?

Comment: Please provide code for the simplest test that you are struggling to create.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the code in the question because it's syntactically incorrect. Could you please fix it? `var bookList = DataRetriever<Book, AuthorFilter>List(authorFilter);` and `Func<Book>, List<Book>> bookListFunc`

Comment: DataRetriever<Book, AuthorFilter>.List(authorFilter);

Basically, a class is calling a static function DataRetriever.List, how do you mock it?

Comment: Or, I'm sorry. Was really confused by the syntax. Yes, it syntactically correct.

Comment: You can't mock static classes. You should inject the class via DI, then you mock it easily

Comment: I know.  But that is legacy codes all over the places.  I want to check if there is better way to do it.